# Global $post not working in OOP function WordPress

Tags: posts, plugin-development, custom-field, comment-form, globals

I added a custom field with comment form. Below is my code.First function return post id when using var_dump function.But the last function return NULL always.

```
class Post_Rating_Public_Helper {

    public static function prp_change_comment_form_defaults($commentdata, $comment_id = null ) {
        global $check;
        global $wpdb, $post;

        //// get rating value from database
        $ratingValues = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT meta_value FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."commentmeta WHERE meta_key = 'rating'");
        $results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT option_value FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."options WHERE option_name = 'prp_settings'");

        var_dump($post->ID); // return post id

        $a = unserialize($results[0]->option_value);
        $b = $a['checkbox1'];
        $check = $a['checkbox1'];
        $stars_label = $a['rtlabel'];
        if($stars_label !== ''){
            $st_label = $stars_label;
        }else{
            $st_label = 'Please rate';
        }

        $arraytype= array();
        $post_type = get_post_type($post->ID);
        if(!empty($a)){
            foreach($a as $key => $type){
                if($type === $post_type){
                    $arraytype[] = $type;

                }
            }
        }

        if($b == 'yes'){
            if(!empty($arraytype)){
                if (in_array($post_type, $arraytype)) {
                    if(!isset($_GET['replytocom'])){
        echo '<fieldset class="rating">
        <legend>'.$st_label.'<span class="required">*</span></legend>
        <input type="radio" id="star5" name="rating" value="5" /><label for="star5" title="Rocks!">5 stars</label>
        <input type="radio" id="star4" name="rating" value="4" /><label for="star4" title="Pretty good">4 stars</label>
        <input type="radio" id="star3" name="rating" value="3" /><label for="star3" title="Meh">3 stars</label>
        <input type="radio" id="star2" name="rating" value="2" /><label for="star2" title="Kinda bad">2 stars</label>
        <input type="radio" id="star1" name="rating" value="1" /><label for="star1" title="Sucks big time">1 star</label>
        </fieldset>';
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }



    //////// save comment meta data ////////

    public static function prp_save_comment_meta_data( $comment_id ) {
        if ( ( isset( $_POST['rating'] ) ) && ( $_POST['rating'] != "") )
        $rating = wp_filter_nohtml_kses($_POST['rating']);
        add_comment_meta( $comment_id, 'rating', $rating );
    }
    ///////// validate meta field /////////

    public static function prp_validate_comment_meta_data() {
        global $post;
        global $wpdb;
        $results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT option_value FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."options WHERE option_name = 'prp_settings'");
        $getPostID = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT comment_post_ID FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."comments WHERE comment_post_ID = '".$post->ID."' ");
        $a = unserialize($results[0]->option_value); 
        $check = $a['checkbox1'];

        var_dump($post->ID); // return null

        if ( $a['checkbox1'] == 'yes' ) {

        $comment_post = get_post($commentdata['comment_post_ID']); //Get post object
        $post_type = $comment_post->post_type;
        $arraytype= array();

        //exit;
        foreach($a as $type){
            if($type === $post_type){
                    $arraytype[] = $type;
            }
        }   

            //if(!empty($arraytype)){
                //if (in_array($post_type, $arraytype)) {
                    if ( !isset( $_POST['rating'] ) || empty( $_POST['rating'] ) ){
                        if($_POST['comment_parent'] == 0){
                            wp_die( __( 'Error: Please rate this post.' ) );
                        }
                    }   
                //}
            //}
        }
        //return $commentdata;
    }


} //end of class
```

Hooks

```
$this->loader->add_action( 'comment_form_top', $plugin_public, 'prp_change_comment_form_defaults');
        $this->loader->add_action( 'pre_comment_on_post', $plugin_public, 'prp_validate_comment_meta_data', 9);
        $this->loader->add_action( 'comment_post', $plugin_public, 'prp_save_comment_meta_data' );
```

I didn't figure out what's the issue.

Comment: your hooks are wrong pass an array of class name and method name as 2nd param.

Comment: unless that's what your loader does

Answer (score 2):

First function works fine, because comment form is displayed just after post. So it’s the same request and global variable `post` still contains current post.

On the other hand, `comment_post` is run in another request - a POST request containing the newly added comment. So there is no global post object, because no post should be displayed.

That’s why this function [takes `comment_ID` as first param](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/comment_post). This comment is already in DB, so you can select it and then get the post it’s assigned to.

If you want to use post in `comment_post`, you should do it based on its params:

```
add_action( 'comment_post', 'show_message_function', 10, 2 );
function show_message_function( $comment_ID, $comment_approved ) {
    $comment = get_comment( $comment_ID );
     $post_ID = $comment->comment_post_ID;
     ...
}
```

So... It has nothing to do with OOP. It’s about when and where is given function called and what global variables are available then.

Comment: Thanks. I send post id with hidden field from first function then get post id in third function using $_POST['id'];

Comment: Can you send some code example with your answer?

Comment: @ShoaibSaleem where do you do that? All I can see in your third function is you’re trying to use global `post` variable, then do a lot of strange queries, that make no sense, and so on... What code would you like to see posted? Your question is “why...”. I think I’ve already explained it...

Comment: What is your way to get post id in third function?

Comment: @ShoaibSaleem It’s not my way - It’s the only correct way. Stop ignoring params of hook callbacks.